# An invalid answer to a Yes or No statement

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string mood;

int main()
    {
        cout << "Are you feeling happy today?" << endl;
        cin >> mood;
        if (mood == "yes" || mood == "Yes")
            {
                cout << "Great! Glad you're happy!" << endl;
            }
        if (mood == "no" || mood == "No")
            {
                cout << "That's unfortunate, hope you feel better." << endl;
            }
        if (mood == "unsure" || mood == "Unsure")
            {
                cout << "At least you're alive!" << endl;
            }
        else
            cout << "Please answer with 'yes', 'no' or 'unsure'" << endl;

            // How would I make this loop back to asking the user the
            // "Are you feeling happy today" again?

    return 0;
    }
```

I was wondering how in a "Yes" or "No" question, if the user put anything other than "Yes" or "No" if I would be able to loop back to asking to user the initial question. Would I need to be a while loop? And if so, can someone explain how?

Comment: Yes a loop would be a good starting point. Try to experiment a little your self first.

Comment: You should also  think about that chain of `if` statements. What do you think happens if the user enters e.g. `"yes"`? Think about that and then look at the `if` statement for checking for `"unsure"`, if the input is `"yes"` what would happen in that last `if` statement?

Comment: By the way, I recommend you to transform the user input to upper or lower so you do not have the need for or in your conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution: make a loop that basically can loop forever, asking the same question again and againd, but break it on a valid answer:

```
int main()
{
    string mood;

    while(1)
    {
        cout << "Are you feeling happy today?" << endl;
        cin >> mood;
        if (mood == "yes" || mood == "Yes")
        {
            cout << "Great! Glad you're happy!" << endl;
            break;
        }
        if (mood == "no" || mood == "No")
        {
            cout << "That's unfortunate, hope you feel better." << endl;
            break;
        }
        if (mood == "unsure" || mood == "Unsure")
        {
            cout << "At least you're alive!" << endl;
            break;
        }

        cout << "Please answer with 'yes', 'no' or 'unsure'" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to show you some more complicated soultion, but I would prefer this due to easier modification of acceptable answers. I hope you find it useful!
I also recommend to convert user input to lower case for keep the length of your `acceptable` vector low.

-EDIT- (thanks to [bolov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2805305/bolov))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> acceptable = {"yes", "no", "unsure"};

int main() {
  std::string message;
  while(std::end(acceptable) == std::find(std::begin(acceptable), std::end(acceptable), message))
    std::cin >> message;
}
```

You could use `std::map`, to map answer to user input as well. Probaply you should call `accpt.find(msg)` once, but I think it's not a big deal in this case :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

std::map<std::string, std::string> accpt = {
  {"yes", "yes was given"},
  {"no", "no was given"},
  {"unsure", "unsure was given"}
};

int main() {
  std::string msg;
  while(accpt.find(msg) == accpt.end())
    std::cin >> msg;
  std::cout << accpt.find(msg)->second;
}
```

Comment: `initializeAcceptable` is a C idiom. C++ has constructors. Use them. e. g. `std::vector<std::string> acceptable = {"yes", "no", "unsafe"}`

Comment: c++ has the standard library, specifically the [Algorithms library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). Use it. [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

Comment: thank your for highlighting my mistakes! I'll correct it as soon as possible :)

Comment: they were not mistakes. Just that there are easier/better ways to accomplish the same things.